# Why is this code generating extra commas?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript

```
function chkout_pp(i) {
    var myarray = new Array();
    var li = 1;
    myarray[0] = ""
    for(j = 1; j < 13; j++)
    {
        if ($('#chkpp'+j).is(':checked') == true) {  
            myarray[li] = $('#chkpp'+j).val()+"<br>";
            li++;
        }
    } 
    $("#ownerarray").val(myarray);
    $("#edmt_pp").html(myarray+"");
}
```

This code is generating commas. I want to remove the commas. Is there anyone that can answer my question?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is unreadable now.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are zero commas being created by that code.  Not a single one.

Comment: Your question and title don't really make sense. You're asking a Javascript question, which is unclear and have a title that says "PHP With Wordpress". Are you trying to trim the BR tag off the end of your list item or something?

Comment: i see a syntax error in line 4 of the code,no semi-colon. and  this code does not have COMMA in any reference watsoever

Comment: It seems that it's not this code that is creating comma's. What are you inputting in this function?

Answer (score 2):

There are commas being generated in this code.

```
$("#edmt_pp").html(myarray + "");
```

There's an implicit `myarray.toString()` here, which will join the array elements together with commas.

To avoid that, do:

```
$("#edmt_pp").html(myarray.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **very** difficult to understand what you are asking, but I believe the problem is that you are using an array, so when you do

```
 $("#edmt_pp").html(myarray+"");
```

JS converts it to a string, hence putting commas in between the elements.

Use a string instead:

```
function chkout_pp(i) {
    var mystring = "";
    var li = 1;

    for(j = 1; j < 13; j++)
    {
        if ($('#chkpp'+j).is(':checked') == true) {  
            mystring = mystring + $('#chkpp'+j).val()+"<br>";
            li++;
        }
    } 
    $("#ownerarray").val(mystring);
    $("#edmt_pp").html(mystring);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I feel stupid now. The reason it is returning commas is most likely because `$("#edmt_pp").html(myarray+"");` is coercing a type conversion from your array variable to a string (which incidentally prints out each element separated by a comma).